# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in google script while i was creating event from GoogleAppsScript to Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling, syntax-error

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("lap_prac_conf")[0].createEvent(Laptop_model,5/12/2020 11:00:00,5/13/2020 10:00:00,{Decription:name});
    //alert("hi");
```

What is the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("lap_prac_conf")[0].createEvent("Laptop_model",new Date(2020,4,12,11),new Date(2020,4,13,10),{Description:"name"});
```

The signature for createEvent is String, Date, Date, Object);

You were using strings for dates and you also spelled description incorrectly and you also didn't have quotes around the first string.

Since you didn't provide a complete script I can't tell if Laptop_model and name are declared variable.

[createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))

Comment: What is the error? Share a little more of the code. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Can you show what worked for you so that people who read the question in the future can benefit from your knowledge.